# rabbitmq integration to Splunk

Tags: rabbitmq, splunk

Recently I installed Rabbit MQ in Centos8 for my company. We also using Splunk Enterprise so we wants to integrate our Rabbit MQ to Splunk and we wants to see, search, check our logs which is coming from Rabbit MQ to in Splunk . How can I do that I don't know. I google it but I didn't get info about it. May anybody help to me for this goal ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The scripts at https://github.com/jerrykuch/rabbitmq-splunk are somewhat old, but should still be functional. It can leverage the HTTP API to pull in the relevant data. That page also lists the recommended files to monitor

Answer (score 0):

Always check [Splunkbase](https://splunkbase.splunk.com) when looking for ingesting data types - often there exist apps and add-ons that will do what you're looking for

Here are two related to RabbiMQ:

- JMS Messaging Modular Input - https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1317/#/details
- AMQP Messaging Modular Input - https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1812/#/details